# MySQL Selecting information from a table based on matching information from a second table

Tags: mysql

I've got a problem that I'm having difficulty finding a work-around for. I'm working with MySQL to see if it's a good fit for the company that I'm working for, and I've been thrilled with its capabilities thus far. I've run into a snag, however, and I was hoping someone here could help me out!

I've got two tables in my database, one for contractors and another for loan numbers. My contractors table holds information such as their name, contact details, and the areas that they are willing to perform work. These areas are formatted by (county, state), and if there are multiple, they are separated like so:

Anne Arundel, MD;Baltimore, MD;Calvert, MD;

Some contractors, however, are willing to perform work across an entire state. There is another column labelled states for this case, and it is formatted like so:

VA;OH;PA;

My loans table contains a loan number, the (county, state) like above, (but there will only be one entry for any given loan), and a third state column that is redundant and will likely be taken out.

I've been writting a program to manage all of our contractors and loan numbers, and I need to be able to produce a list of contractors who are available for work for any given loan number. Here's the query I've used so far:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM contractors INNER JOIN loans ON contractors.county_state LIKE CONCAT('%', loans.county_state, ';%') WHERE loans.loan_number = <LOAN NUMBER GOES HERE>
```

This works great, but it fails to match contractors who have coverage over the entire state. How do I put something like an OR clause in there that will include the state-wide coverage contractors?

```
OR contractors.states LIKE CONCAT('%', loans.state, ';%')
```

Is something like this possible, or do I have to change direction?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Yeah, seems like you can just do the `OR` like that, but be careful with how you're requiring a semicolon to follow the state name.  In your second listing of states (VA;OH;PA), there is no trailing semi-colon.  You'd be better off storing those states as discrete records in a separate relational table.

Comment: @Marc  Actually, there is supposed to be another trailing semi-colon there. I didn't realize I excluded it! I'll go ahead and test it out some more. Seems like I got some errors when I tried it though... Would the OR clause just sit at the end of the query?

Comment: I would suggest that you properly normalize your database design, moving the states for a contractor off into a separate table with one row per contractor / state

Comment: The OR clause needs to be in the JOIN....ON X OR Y, and NOT in the WHERE clause since ON includes more rows and WHERE potentially reduces the rows.

Comment: @Lukos That explains why I was having issues then. Stupid mistake on my part, ;P  Anyways, thanks for the help everyone! It's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function called FIND_IN_SET which is there to find a value in a comma separated list of values. In this case you would have to replace the **;** with a **,**

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM contractors 
INNER JOIN loans 
ON contractors.county_state LIKE CONCAT('%', loans.county_state, ';%') 
OR FIND_IN_SET(contractors.county_stat, REPLACE(loans.states, ';', ','))
WHERE loans.loan_number = <LOAN NUMBER GOES HERE>
```

This will not be efficient though, and has other problems (such as needing to size your fields to accept the largest number of states, and not being able to use indexes to access the data quickly). It would be better to split the data off into multiple rows in a separate table

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as it turns out, I just had the placement of my OR clause incorrect... Thanks Marc and Lukos for your help! Final code looks something like this:

```
Select first_name, last_name FROM contractors INNER JOIN loans ON contractors.county_state LIKE CONCAT('%', loans.county_state, ';%') OR contractors.states LIKE CONCAT('%', <STATE TO MATCH GOES HERE>, ';%') WHERE loans.loan_number = <LOAN NUMBER GOES HERE>;
```

I'm parsing the state portion on my end through the program I've been developing, but it works like a charm. Thanks again everyone!